# Unnecessary repetition of declaration

Tags: python, scope, string-formatting

This program works just fine as it is, but time = "%s:%s" % (hour, minute) has to be repeated in each if statement. I have placed it in all other scopes and places but I can't figure out why it has to be repeated rather than declaring it once outside of the if statements or any other location for that matter.

```
def minutesToHours():
    hour = 0
    entry = input("How many minutes? I will convert it to hours...")

    if 0 <= entry < 60:
        minute = entry
        time = "%s:%s" % (hour, minute)
        print time
    elif entry >= 60:
        hour = entry / 60
        minute = entry % 60
        time = "%s:%s" % (hour, minute)
        print time
    else:
        print "Please enter a number greater than zero next time."

minutesToHours()

input()
```

Comment: you can't assign 'time' at the top of the code for instance, because 'minute' is not defined yet.

Comment: Python does not have declarations; it's just a simple assignment.

Comment: In previous iterations of my code I assigned 'minute' and 'hour' each to zero at the top. I just didn't mention specifically what I had tried so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `if` statement in the first place:

```
hour, minute = divmod(int(entry), 60)
time = "%s:%s" % (hour, minute)
```

or even:

```
time = "%s:%s" % divmod(int(entry), 60)
```

Here's the [divmod](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) documentation

Comment: Great! I had yet to discover the divmod() function. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refactorize some code.

1. You can ask the user to input a number while `entry` isn't a number.
2. You don't need `if` statement, since compute the modulo is the same with `entry` greater than 60 or not. You can use [`divmod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) to do the division and modulo.
3. So the display can be unified

With all these suggestions:

```
def minutesToHours():
    entry = ""
    while not entry.isdigit():
        if entry != "":
             print "Please enter a number greater than zero next time."
        entry = input("How many minutes? I will convert it to hours...")

    hour, minutes = divmod(int(entry), 60)
    time = "%s:%s" % (hour, minutes)
    print time

minutesToHours()

input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `hour` doesn't exist until you define it in terms of `entry` just above its use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lambda

```
def minutesToHours():

    time = lambda hour, minute: '%s: %s' % (hour, minute)
    hour = 0
    entry = input("How many minutes? I will convert it to hours...")

    if 0 <= entry < 60:
        minute = entry
    elif entry >= 60:
        hour = entry / 60
        minute = entry % 60
    else:
        print "Please enter a number greater than zero next time."
        return

    print time(hour, minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def minutesToHours():
    entry = input("How many minutes? I will convert it to hours...")
    if entry < 0:
        print "Please enter a number greater than zero next time."
    else:
        print "%02d:%02d" % divmod(entry,60)        

minutesToHours()

input()
```